# How to use enum in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, enums

I am making a Flutter app in which you can sign in with a Google Account. I would like to add this enum to the program:

```
enum AuthStatus {
  NOT_DETERMINED,
  NOT_LOGGED_IN,
  LOGGED_IN,
}
 if (user != null) {
          _userId = user?.uid;
        }
        authStatus =
            user?.uid == null ? AuthStatus.NOT_LOGGED_IN : AuthStatus.LOGGED_IN;
```

This way I could make a proper loading screen. My question is where should I put this code and how?

Comment: put the `enum` anywhere, you can treat it as a class in terms of scope. For the sake of simplicity, put it in the same class/file as where you want to access it in. Put the remaining `if...` code in the method you want to put the functionality in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treat them as values, for example

```
AuthStatus _authStatus = NOT_DETERMINED;

if(_authStatus == NOT_DETERMINED){
 tryLogin();
}

tryLogin(){
 //login
 _authStatus = LOGGED_IN;
}
```

just declare them outside any class on global level